# CMakeTools: How to set command line arguments for cmake autoconfigure in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I enabled cmake autoconfiguration of the project whenever the project opens in vscode (`cmake.configureOnOpen`). This stopped working and upon investigating I found that cmake always executes this line:

```
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --no-warn-unused-cli -DMYLIB_TESTS=ON -DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/clang++-14 -S/home/sbeer/dev/MyProject -B/home/sbeer/dev/MyProject/build -G Ninja
```

However this command fails:

```
[cmake]   It fails with the following output:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Change Dir: '/home/sbeer/dev/MeteoCache/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-pkX4BI'
[cmake]     
[cmake]     Run Build Command(s): /usr/bin/ninja -v cmTC_e9309
[cmake]     [1/2] /usr/bin/clang++-14    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9309.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9309.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9309.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/sbeer/dev/MeteoCache/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-pkX4BI/testCXXCompiler.cxx
[cmake]     [2/2] : && /usr/bin/clang++-14   CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9309.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_e9309   && :
[cmake]     FAILED: cmTC_e9309 
[cmake]     : && /usr/bin/clang++-14   CMakeFiles/cmTC_e9309.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_e9309   && :
[cmake]     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
[cmake]     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[cmake]     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

However when I remove the hardcoded `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` options it configures fine! My question now is where do I accomplish this for cmake autoconfigure? I checked all my vscode settings and it appears you would configure the cli arguments in `cmake.configureArgs`, yet this is all I have for the project (workspace):

```
"cmake.configureArgs": [
    "-DMYLIB_TESTS=ON",
    "-DCMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE=ON"
],
```

And the settings for user and projects are even empty.

Where do I influence the command line that the cmake tools extension puts out to configure the project?

(on a sidenote I'm really wondering about this `-lstdc++` library... looks like a type I didn't make...)

**EDIT**: I found another option you could edit: `cmake.configureSettings` can also be used to define variables for the commandline. However, it is not configured in neither default/user/workspace settings in my case, so that can't be it.

Comment: this question is all over the place. you clearly know how to set `cmake.configureArgs`, but the problem seems related to compiler selection. what compilers are being used when you don't specify them? add `message("CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")` after your call to `project()` and run configuration without specifying compilers via commandline.

Comment: are you using [kits](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/kits.md)? presets? I assume kits. what kit have you selected?

Comment: @starball The c++ compiler is used (/usr/bin/c++) if i just use the cli which i think is gcc 11. Interestingly, if I configure cmake tools with a different kit (gcc in that case) it configures fine. Just the clang configuration seems to be broken. I don't use presets.

Comment: if you're using the CLI, then the selected CMake kit is irrelevant to build. show the output of `clang++-14 --version`

Comment: @starball I know, but what I mean is that on the cli the default compiler gets selected which is c++ (or g++). clang++14 --version output is:
`Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin`

Comment: check https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cannot+find+-lstdc%2B%2B%3A+No+such+file+or+directory%22+clang%2B%2B+site%3Astackoverflow.com